# How to highlight the Table row based on Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm working on Google webApp Crud data generated from Google sheets. The search is working all fine, but I'm trying to highlight certain rows based on the data value in Column 7.

E.g If the row contains in Column 7 "PROCESSING" I want to highlight that row with an Orange color in order to focus on that particular data.

These are my script files

**search.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover"  >
      <thead>
        <tr >
          
          <th scope="col">Ref</th>
          <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
          <th scope="col">Color</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Rent</th>
          <th scope="col">Lcoation</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Send</th>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="searchResults" >
    
       
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    
    <template id="rowTemplate" >
     <tr >
          
          <td class="L1"></td>
          <td class="L2"></td>
          <td class="L3"></td>
          <td class="L4"></td>
          <td class="L5"></td>
          <td class="L6"></td>
          <td class="L7"></td>
          <td class="L8"></td>
    
      </tr>
    </template>
```

**main.html**

```
  var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
    var template = templateBox.content;
    
    searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";
    
    resultsArray.forEach(function(r){
    
    var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
    var l1Column = tr.querySelector(".L1");
    var l2Column = tr.querySelector(".L2");
    var l3Column = tr.querySelector(".L3");
    var l4Column = tr.querySelector(".L4");
    var l5Column = tr.querySelector(".L5");
    var l6Column = tr.querySelector(".L6");
    var l7Column = tr.querySelector(".L7");
    var l8Column = tr.querySelector(".L8");
    
    l1Column.innerHTML = r[0];
    l2Column.innerHTML = r[1];
    l3Column.innerHTML = r[2];
    l4Column.innerHTML = r[3];
    l5Column.innerHTML = r[4];
    l6Column.innerHTML = r[5];
    l7Column.innerHTML = r[6];
    l8Column.innerHTML = r[7];
    
    searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
    
    });
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve my expectation?

### **UPDATE**
This is something I'm working on but I exactly don't know how to apply to the above code.

```
<!--Script to add row colour to the table based on value-->
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function(){
hightlightRows();
});

function hightlightRows(){
$('#table tr.in_out td').each(function(){
if ($(this).text() == 'RECEIVED') {
$(this).parent().css('background-color','#d4edda')
$(this).parent().css('color','#3d774b')
}
else if ($(this).text() == 'PROCESSING') {
$(this).parent().css('background-color','#FCD5D5')
$(this).parent().css('color','red')
}

else if ($(this).text() == 'SOLD') {

$(this).parent().css('color','#AEB6BF')
}

}); 
}

</script>

<!--END Script to add row colour to the table based on value-->
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Rubén I've updated the post with a sample code I'm working on, but I don't know how exactly to add to the above code which is little complicated since it's a table with Template has search results...than normal table. I've been watching this video to create the Crud, Here is the video you can exactly watch how the table search table template is been created https://youtu.be/1CSPpsBGlQ0?t=563

Answer (score 0):

Like This?
You can add class when the row is processing and remove it when it finisned

---

**----Update----**

I don't know how you define what is the processing is, so i just simply set the attribute to random column to indicate that whether in processing (see the html code)

```js
let result = document.getElementById("searchResults"); // get the result 
let rows = result.children; // the rows of result
    for (let row of rows) { // loop through all the rows
        for (let column of row.children) { // loop through all the column from the row
            if (column.getAttribute("processing") === "true") { // if any column has attribute "processing"
                row.classList.add("processing"); // set the row to yellow
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.processing {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Ref</th>
                <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
                <th scope="col">Color</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Rent</th>
                <th scope="col">Lcoation</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Send</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="searchResults">
            <tr>
                <td class="L1">L1</td>
                <td class="L2">L2</td>
                <td class="L3">L3</td>
                <td class="L4">L4</td>
                <td class="L5">L5</td>
                <td class="L6">L6</td>
                <td class="L7">L7</td>
                <td class="L8">L8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="L1">L1</td>
                <td class="L2">L2</td>
                <td class="L3">L3</td>
                <td class="L4">L4</td>
                <td class="L5" processing="true">L5</td>
                <td class="L6">L6</td>
                <td class="L7">L7</td>
                <td class="L8">L8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="L1">L1</td>
                <td class="L2">L2</td>
                <td class="L3">L3</td>
                <td class="L4">L4</td>
                <td class="L5">L5</td>
                <td class="L6">L6</td>
                <td class="L7">L7</td>
                <td class="L8" processing="true">L8</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice, but it didn't work for this code :(

Comment: It's highlighting only the first row, it's not highlighting any of the row in Column 6 that contains Processing

Comment: If you want to highlight particular row that in processing, you should loop through all the rows in the table, then loop through all the column from the row, if any of the column that is Processing, then just add the class ".processing" to the row

Comment: I'm not a coder, I made the above code by watching YouTube, I tried many ways to get this done but failed :(, can you please assist me to work on the loop function?

Comment: I have updated the answer, see if you can understand it.

Comment: Sorry  時雨初 , It didn't work, It actually messed up the entire table format. :( Thank you for all your time.